# Prevent the ItemsControl from changing the focus when clicked (Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight

I have an ItemsControl that host some input controls (textboxes, etc). When I click in the background of the ItemsControl, the focus is automatically changed to the first item in the ItemsControl.

Is there a way to prevent this? I already tried overriding OnGotFocus on the ItemsControl without calling base but it did not worked.

Thanks in advanced!

Jacques.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out what was causing the first element to get the focus. In my case, I am using a ScrollViewer hosting a custom ItemsControl. The ItemsControl and container inside of it have IsTabStop set to false. The change of focus is made by the ScrollViewer in the OnMouseLeftButtonDown method.

Since the ScrollViewer is sealed, I had to override the OnMouseLeftButtonDown on my container and ItemsControl to set e.Handled to true. This solved my issue.